# URLRewriting in web.config not working

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting

I have been asked to move an ASP.NET 4.0 web site from GoDaddy to Arvixe. I have setup VS 2012 with the project solution and configured it to publish the site to the Arvixe server. After adjusting the database connection strings in web.config, the site works. *sigh*

However this is a huge site with a huge database and lots of menu items. The menu items are not working - I get an HTTP 404 Not Found error on most all of them. The links relate to url rewrites in web.config. There are at least 100 of these rewrites but I don't know why they aren't working.

Here is an example:

```
  <urlrewritingnet rewriteOnlyVirtualUrls="true" contextItemsPrefix="QueryString" xmlns="http://www.urlrewriting.net/schemas/config/2006/07">
    <rewrites>

       ...

       <add name="mycategory" virtualUrl="^~/my-stuff/(.+)$" redirectMode="Permanent" rewriteUrlParameter="ExcludeFromClientQueryString" destinationUrl="~/mycategory.aspx?rct=$1" ignoreCase="true" />

       ...

    </rewrites>
  </urlrewritingnet>
```

I've checked the majority of these lines to ensure that the .aspx being specified in `destinationUrl` actually exists and it does. In the above example mycategory.aspx exists in the root folder.

Is there something I need to configure before these rewrites will work? Like something that needs to be enabled - or perhaps a certain support required by Arvixe? Btw, this is installed on a Business Class ASP Pro account.

**UPDATE**

I feel silly, but I went into the control panel on Arvixe and changed ASP.NET from 4.0 to 4.0 Integrated Pipeline. This resolved the problem above but has caused different one...

DNS is not configured for this web site yet and so I am accessing it by IP address. At this point, the home page loads fine and all of the menu items work correctly. Images load fine also, but when I click on anything and go to a new page all links in the page as well as menu items have the IP address replaced with 'localhost' and this of course breaks the site.

For example:

`http://123.123.123.123/my-category/` and `<img src="123.123.123.123/images/myimage.png"/>`

gets replaced with:

`http://localhost/my-category/` and `<img src="localhost/images/myimage.png"/>`

Does anyone have a clue how I might overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I apologize for cluttering SO with this question. As per my update, changing ASP.NET from 4.0 to 4.0 Integrated Pipeline resolved my initial question. My second question was resolved by changing `<add key="SiteUrl" value="http://localhost/" />`.

:S

Thank you to anyone who pondered any ideas to help. Hopefully this post will help someone else.